# How to overlay level plots in R?

Tags: r, graphics, imaging

In R, say you wish to present statistical data on an image background- like in medical imaging

[image: example produced with Mango]

Each layer is a different matrix. 
Here is a non-sense example:

- `volcano` in gray
- `B<- (volcano>160) * rnorm(prod(dim(volcano))` in
  heat colors.

How would you go about?

Comment: Are you familiar with this JSS publication by Paul Murrell, [Raster Images in R Graphics](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `image` function can do this, just set the transparancy of the 2nd set of colors and overlay it using `add=TRUE`.  Any missing values will be completely transparent and you can set the alpha level for the other colors (of course your graphics device has to support partial transparancy for this to work).  Here is a quick example:

```
A <- t(volcano)[ncol(volcano):1,]
B <- (A>160) * rnorm(prod(dim(A)) )

B[ A < 120 ] <- NA  # show some complete transparency

image(A, col=grey( seq(0,1,length.out=12) ) )  # initial plot
hc <- sub('FF$','77',heat.colors(12)) # convert heat colors to have an alpha
image(B, add=TRUE, col=hc)  # overlay the new plot
```